# CX_Freeze EXE not working on non-mapped network drive

Tags: python, python-3.x, cx-freeze, bing-ads-api

I've been having trouble trying to getting the program to run on a network drive. The program works if run locally or run with a driver letter set to the location such as Z:\drive. It seems only bingads module causes this.

For some reason its adding extra slashes to the path. "\\\\\\Drive\\folder\\folder\\lib\\bingads\\v12\\proxies\\campaign_management_service.xml". I am using Python 3.6 on Windows 7 and this is my 1st time working on python. Bingads is already included in packages setup. The error code that shows up is [WinError 161].

I added all the packages I need to 'packages' setup. I'm also using CX_Freeze 6.0. Using 6.1 caused the tkinter folders tcl and tk to not copy to the build directory.

OS:Win 7 64 bit

Python ver: 3.6

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HnDeH.png)

[setup.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kwgMb.png)

Comment: looks like it doesn't know what `localfile` is

Comment: @SuperStew thanks for the reply, I don't know what do to about that. The code is part of what Python included. The Program works locally, but not on network drive

Comment: As you think bingads is the cause of the error, what did they say when you raised an issue on the bingads github?

Comment: @barny I haven't tried asking yet. I'll do that now